# Evaluating linear model with new data returns fitted values

Tags: r, lm, predict, poly

I am constructing and evaluating my model as shown below.

```
yData <- rnorm(10)
xData <- matrix(rnorm(20), 10, 2)
polyModel <- lm(yData~polym(xData, degree=2, raw=T))
newData <- matrix(rnorm(100), 50, 2)
yPredicted <- predict(polyModel, polym(newData, degree=2, raw=T))
```

However, the model evaluation `yPredicted` just equals the fitted values `polyModel$fitted.values`, a vector of length 10. I was expecting `yPredicted` to be a vector of length 50 in this case. Some help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`predict()` doesn't work very well unless the data is specified in the `data` argument.  This appears to work:

```
polyModel <- lm(yData~poly(V1, V2, degree=2, raw=TRUE),
                data=as.data.frame(xData))
length(fitted(polyModel))  ## 10
newData <- matrix(rnorm(100), 50, 2)
yPredicted <- predict(polyModel, newdata=as.data.frame(newData))
length(yPredicted) ## 50
```

- `V1` and `V2` are the default column names assigned when you convert a matrix into a data frame.
- this specification wouldn't work wello if you had an unknown and/or large number of columns to put into the polynomial (e.g. `poly(V1, ..., V1000, degree=2, raw=TRUE)`)

If you don't know the number of columns in advance, a *slightly* hacky solution would be:

```
f <- as.formula(sprintf("yData~poly(%s, degree=2, raw=TRUE)",
           paste("V", seq(ncol(xData)), sep="", collapse=", "))
polyModel <- lm(f, data=as.frame(xData))
```

(untested)

Comment: I was afraid it had something to do with that. The problem is that I don't know in advance how many columns xData will have. The maximum number of columns is 5. Worst case I could just make a case switch and type out the different scenarios (V1) / (V1, V2) / (V1, V2, V3)... but I'd prefer not to. Is there any way to extend this to a variable number of columns in xData?